# I can't get Applescript to tell illustrator to make strokes with registration color

Tags: applescript

This is a script to set up any document as a print template with guides and registration marks. This does what I want except making the registration marks registration color (stroke no fill). Any help appreciated - thank you.

```
tell application "Adobe Illustrator"

    --(resize page)        
    set newWidth to 12
    set newWidthPoints to newWidth * 72 -- (1 inch = 72 points)
    set newHeight to 18.25
    set newHeightPoints to newHeight * 72 -- (1 inch = 72 points)
    set artboard rectangle of artboard 1 of document 1 to {0.0, 0.0, newWidthPoints, -newHeightPoints}

    tell document 1

            --(New Layer)                
            make new layer

            --(make guides)(vertical)
            set Rectangle1 to make new rectangle
            set width of Rectangle1 to 0
            set height of Rectangle1 to 1458
            set position of Rectangle1 to {432, 72}
            --horizontal                
            set Rectangle2 to make new rectangle
            set width of Rectangle2 to 1008
            set height of Rectangle2 to 0
            set position of Rectangle2 to {-72, -90}

            set guides of every page item of layer 1 to true


            make new layer


            set ReggieProps to {filled:false, stroked:true, stroke color:{tint:100.0, spot:[registration color]}}


            --make center registration mark
            set Rectangle3 to make new rectangle with ReggieProps
            set width of Rectangle3 to 0.15
            set height of Rectangle3 to 40
            set position of Rectangle3 to {432, 20}

            set Rectangle4 to make new rectangle with ReggieProps
            set width of Rectangle4 to 40
            set height of Rectangle4 to 0.15
            set position of Rectangle4 to {412, 0}

            set Square1 to make new rectangle with ReggieProps
            set width of Square1 to 28
            set height of Square1 to 28
            set position of Square1 to {418, 14}

            set Circle1 to make new ellipse with ReggieProps
            set width of Circle1 to 27
            set height of Circle1 to 27
            set position of Circle1 to {418.5, 14}

            --make left side registration mark

            set Rectangle5 to make new rectangle with ReggieProps
            set width of Rectangle5 to 0.15
            set height of Rectangle5 to 40
            set position of Rectangle5 to {20, 20}

            set Rectangle6 to make new rectangle with ReggieProps
            set width of Rectangle6 to 40
            set height of Rectangle6 to 0.15
            set position of Rectangle6 to {0, 0}

            set Square2 to make new rectangle with ReggieProps
            set width of Square2 to 28
            set height of Square2 to 28
            set position of Square2 to {6, 14}

            set Circle2 to make new ellipse with ReggieProps
            set width of Circle2 to 27
            set height of Circle2 to 27
            set position of Circle2 to {6.5, 14}

            --make right side registration mark

            set Rectangle7 to make new rectangle with ReggieProps
            set width of Rectangle7 to 0.15
            set height of Rectangle7 to 40
            set position of Rectangle7 to {844, 20}

            set Rectangle8 to make new rectangle with ReggieProps
            set width of Rectangle8 to 40
            set height of Rectangle8 to 0.15
            set position of Rectangle8 to {824, 0}

            set Square3 to make new rectangle with ReggieProps
            set width of Square3 to 28
            set height of Square3 to 28
            set position of Square3 to {830, 14}

            set Circle3 to make new ellipse with ReggieProps
            set width of Circle3 to 27
            set height of Circle3 to 27
            set position of Circle3 to {830.5, 14}



    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `spot` value and `make` command are both written incorrectly. Fixes for the above code:

```
    tell document 1

        ...

        set ReggieProps to {filled:false, stroked:true, ¬
                stroke color:{tint:100.0, spot:spot "[Registration]"}}

        set Rectangle3 to make new rectangle with properties ReggieProps

        ...
```

As a bonus, here's a more compact, reusable `drawRegistrationMark` handler that avoids all that copy-pasta:

```
on drawRegistrationMark(x, y)
    tell application "Adobe Illustrator"
        my drawRegPath(rectangle, 0.15, 40, {x + 20, y + 20})
        my drawRegPath(rectangle, 40, 0.15, {x, y})
        my drawRegPath(rectangle, 28, 28, {x + 6, y + 14})
        my drawRegPath(ellipse, 27, 27, {x + 6.5, y + 14})
    end tell
end drawRegistrationMark

on drawRegPath(theShape, theWidth, theHeight, thePosition)
    tell document 1 of application "Adobe Illustrator"
        make new theShape with properties {width:theWidth, height:theHeight, ¬
                position:thePosition, filled:false, stroked:true, ¬
                stroke color:{tint:100.0, spot:spot "[Registration]"}}
    end tell
end drawRegPath


-- make registration marks

drawRegistrationMark(412, 0) -- center
drawRegistrationMark(0, 0) -- left side
drawRegistrationMark(824, 0) -- right side
```

I do have to ask though: why don't you just use AI's Print dialog to add reg marks, etc. when printing the document? Or the Marks and Bleeds option when saving as a PDF?

Comment: Thank you! I do appreciate the help.

Comment: I do prefer to use the registration marks generated by illustrator and it also saves film but I recently went back to work at a shop I worked a couple of years ago and they are pretty set in their ways and prefer the registration marks like the ones this script makes. The real problem was the info in the slug is too small and hard to read once the film positives are transferred to screens ( screen printing shop). I posted a question at Adobe about how to enlarge the text generated by Illustrator but received no answer. If I could figure out how to generate 12-14 pt text from there I would,

Comment: Can't help you there, I'm afraid. You could try Adobe support, although if it was customizable I suspect folks on the user forums would already know.